# How to get child nodes in XML::LibXML by node type?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, libxml2, cdata

I'm parsing complex XML documents, and one section might look like this:

```
<mds>
  <md>
    <value>
      <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><record>...</record>]]>
    </value>
  </md>
</mds>
```

When I'm parsing the value node, it actually contains 3 child nodes, two empty ones and one cdata node. Is there a way to easily just get the cdata-node, like

```
my @dcvalues = $dom->findnodes("//mds/md/value");
my @cdatanodes = $dcvalues[0]->find(<some xpath that only returns cdata nodes>);
my $cdataval = $cdatanodes[0]->textContent;
```

You get the idea.
Edit: I'm aware that I could just access the cdata in this example with

```
my $cdatanode = $dcvalues[0]->firstChild->nextSibling;
```

but then I would depend on the cdata always being the second node, which I'm not sure of.

Comment: You can access just the second child with `my @dcvalues = $dom->findnodes('//mds/md/value[2]')`. No need to mess with the DOM calls.

Comment: Someone posted good answer and now its gone, no idea why. He suggested a grep like this: my @cdataList = grep { $_->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE} $dcValues[0]->getChildnodes;. Just in case anyone needs something similiar.

Comment: He deleted it himself after I posted a comment that corrected his XPath. I think he was offended! It's still visible for those with 10,000 reputation or more.

Comment: Thx Borodin. Yes I noted also that somehting wasn't quite right with the xpath, but still it was a valuable answer to me...

Comment: I think I would use just `grep /\S/, @nodes` which removes all nodes containing just whitespace. Note that you could use `$_->isa('XML::LibXML::CDATASection')` which does the same thing as `$_->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE`. There's no way to do this in XPath as a `CDATA` isn't distinguishable from an ordinary text node - it's just a different way of escaping troublesome characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [`no_blanks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Parser#PARSER-OPTIONS) parser option. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<END_XML, {no_blanks => 1});
<mds>
  <md>
    <value>
      <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><record>...</record>]]>
    </value>
  </md>
</mds>
END_XML


my @values = $xml->findnodes('//mds/md/value/text()');

say scalar @values;

say say $values[0]->textContent;
```

**output**

```
1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><record>...</record>
```

Comment: Good one. I also found another one just now: $cdatastr = $dom->findvalue("//mds/md/value"); seems to work just fine... Thanks for the no_blanks option.

Comment: @jackthehipster: Okay. I'm pleased that you found a solution that works for you.